# Normal contact force, friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

If two blocks are resting on top of each other and are on the ground, the weight of the upper block causes an equal and opposite reaction force on the lower one (Newt 3rd) and the same happens for the lower one on the ground

There must be friction between the two blocks but I don't understand how to caluclate it using the empirical formula: $$ f = \mu N$$
Surely the equal and opposite normal forces between the surfaces cancel each other out leaving N = 0.
My approach would be to ignore N1, treat the lower block as the ground for the upper block and let N = W1. But I don't feel like it's right. **How do you compute friction and what do we take as N?**

More generally, my understanding of contact forces (&Newt 3rd law) is weak. **If a string pulls on a mass and the mass pulls equal and oppositely on the string, how can the system move?**

*Not a hwk question, I have the solutions so I don't need any answers, I don't understand the physics behind what's happening hence why I am here*

Comment: There is no friction between the blocks because you show no horizontal applied horizontal force  to either block and friction would only exist if there were some applied horizontal force to oppose.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to talk about friction in the absence of a horizontal force because friction comes into existence in order to oppose some applied force causing motion against a surface (Recall that friction is a self-adjusting force).

So, to answer your question we'll take up the following two cases, where we will ignore the friction between the floor and block for now:

**Case 1: Force is applied on the lower block**
For a small enough force we know from experience that the two blocks move as a whole. This is because the friction between both the blocks acts as a driving force for the upper block:[image: FBD]
The magnitude of this force is given by,
$f_s=\mu N_1$
since we are calculating the frictional force acting on the upper block, we use the normal reaction acting on *itself*.
This same frictional force acts as a retarding force on the lower block so that the final equations of motion are:
$M_1a_1=f_s$, and
$M_2a_2=F-f_s$
So that the condition for the blocks to move together becomes, $a_1=a_2$.

**Case 2: Force is applied on the upper block**
As expected we will observe the inverted equations of motion now, i.e.
$M_1a_1=F-f_s$ and
$M_2a_2=f_s$.

If you now want to find the frictional force between the ground and the block then think about it this way:
Only the lower block will experience this force since it is the one in contact with the ground. What is the *total* normal force that the ground exerts on it? Notice that I'm not asking about the *net* normal reaction it experiences (which would simply be $N_1$).

Now to answer your second question, suppose you are tugging at a string, attached to a mass, with a constant force $F$. Each element of the string will experience a force of tension so that the rope remains intact. This force of tension will be equal and opposite to your applied force. This tension will be transmitted from element to element till it reaches the block as shown:
[image: FBD]

[image: FBD]

Consider the right extreme of the string first:
The first element is pulled by *you* with a force $F$. It then pulls the second element with a force of tension $T$ but because tension being an internal force is self-adjusting, we have $T=F$. The second element now *transmits or communicates* this force as tension to the third element. As a result of Newton's 3rd law it experiences an equal and opposite force such that the net force on the second element is also **zero**. This continues throughout the length of the string till we reach its other extreme connected to the mass. This last element finally pulls the mass with force $F$ (notice how the presence of $F$ is communicated to the block through the length of the string). The block exerts a reactionary force on this last element so that the net force on this too is zero. However, now the block itself experiences a force $F$ to the right which is why it moves. The net force on the string is also only $F$, due to the first element alone. The net force on all the other elements being zero ensures that they don't move relative to each other i.e., the string does not snap.

Thus, our analysis shows that the net force on the string as well as the block is $F$ which is why they move together as a system.

The point to keep in mind is that Newton's third law is applicable to a pair of bodies and that the action and reaction forces never act on the same body.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The weight of the upper block and the normal force exerted by the lower block on the upper block do not constitute an action-reaction pair.  The weight of the upper block is the force that the earth exerts on the upper block, and its reaction pair is the force that the upper block exerts on the earth.  The reaction pair to the normal force the lower block exerts on the upper block is the normal force the upper block exerts on the lower block.

With regard to "the equal and opposite normal forces between the surfaces cancel each other out," please note that when you do a force balance on a body, you include only the forces exerted on the body by other bodies, not the forces it exerts on them. Didn't they teach that to you?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a handle on top of the top block for lifting.  Lift with enough force to "feel" the block, but not enough to lift it.  You are lifting with a force smaller than the top block's weight.  The top block's weight is the same as before, but the bottom block no longer has to push as hard to keep from being crushed.  Your hand and the bottom block are working together to prevent weight due to gravity from pulling the top block through the bottom block.  The normal force between the blocks is smaller, but the net force on the top block is still zero.  Upward pull plus upward normal force on the top block together balance the downward pull of weight.